# Unity Lossy Scaling implementation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, scaling

I am currently working with Unity and transform.rotation. The problem is that I have 2 rotating objects as parent-child. This makes the child scale weirdly and going from a box to a paralelogram. Gooing I found transform.lossyScale that should fix my problem but I don´t know how to implement it.

TL:DR how to implement transform.lossyscale to prevent parent-child scaling issues.

current code

```
float currentR = transform.eulerAngles.x;

    if(currentR < 30){
        transform.Rotate (rotation * Time.deltaTime * 3);
}
```

Comment: `transform.lossyScale` is a read-only value that gives you an *approximation* of the transform's scaling after taking into account all scaling of its parent hierarchy. The only way to fix your problem is to use uniform scales on your parent objects. If you ***must*** have a non-uniform scale, create a separate "empty" game object to be the parent of both objects, with the new child having the non-uniform scale.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, if you don't want the child to inheirt the scale of the parent, don't make it a child of said parent :P 
However. If you must, you can make a child that reverses the scale of the parent (So it would have the opposite scale of the parent)

Than make your new child a child of that child :)

You can use this general purpose script, put this on the child at it shouldn't have any issues being rotated at runtime even if it has a scaled parent :)
(It will do the thing I described above using code)

```
public class IgnoreParentScale : MonoBehaviour {

Transform scaleInversionParent;

void Awake () {
    scaleInversionParent = new GameObject ("ScaleInversionParent").transform;
    scaleInversionParent.SetParent (transform.parent);
    scaleInversionParent.localPosition = Vector3.zero;
    scaleInversionParent.eulerAngles = Vector3.zero;//Zero out anything but the scale
    UpdateScaleInversion ();
    transform.SetParent (scaleInversionParent, true);
}
void LateUpdate () {
    UpdateScaleInversion (); //Only if you are changing the scale at run time.
}
void UpdateScaleInversion () {
    Vector3 invertedScale = scaleInversionParent.parent.localScale;
    invertedScale = new Vector3 (1f / invertedScale.x, 1f / invertedScale.y, 1f / invertedScale.z);
    scaleInversionParent.localScale = invertedScale;//This scale will invert the parents scale
}
}
```

**Alternatively:**

You can use this script to create a new parent that inherits the position and rotation of the original parent, but ignores it's scale.

```
    public class IgnoreParentScale : MonoBehaviour {

    Transform originalParent;
    Transform newParent;

    void Awake () {
        newParent = new GameObject ("").transform;
        originalParent = transform.parent;

        UpdateNewParent ();
        transform.SetParent (newParent);
    }
    public void LateUpdate () {
        UpdateNewParent ();
    }
    void UpdateNewParent () {
        newParent.transform.position = originalParent.transform.position;
        newParent.transform.rotation = originalParent.transform.rotation;
    }
}
```