# How do you scale a parent game-object without scaling the child game-object in Unity 3D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, parent-child, scale

Currently, I have two game-object, one as the parent and the other as a child. When I scale the parent, it also scale the child.  How can I scale the parent game-object without affecting the scale on the child or is there a better way around this problem?  As you can see on the images below, the child gets wrap on the z axis.

[image]

Comment: Simple way would be unparenting, scaling, reparenting.

Comment: That won't work since the child has to follow the parent.

Comment: Never mind.  Problem is solved.

Comment: Create another game object one level up in the hierarchy and attach your current parent and child to that as "siblings." Also, if you've solved the problem, please post an answer to your question as a courtesy to others that may encounter this in the future.

Comment: Thanks 3Dave.  I have written a script that allow the game object to follow another game object without effecting the scaling.

Comment: using UnityEngine;

public class Scale : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject target;
    public Vector3 startPosTarget;
    public Vector3 startPosObj;
    public Vector3 difference;
    void Start()
    {
        startPosTarget = target.transform.position;
        startPosObj = this.transform.position;
    }
    void LateUpdate()
    {
        difference = target.transform.position - startPosTarget;
        this.transform.position = startPosObj + difference;
    }

}

Comment: Hi @Coder, consider [answering your own question in the space below](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47417317/unity-lossy-scaling-implementation/47421193#47421193

Comment: However in your case it looks like these are sprites .. maybe you should rather consider proper [sprite splicing](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/9SliceSprites.html) here?

Comment: Can you splice 3D game-object in unity?